# How to modify tables in Python?

Tags: python, text, io

I have a table in .txt file like this:

```
GROUP TYPE FRACTION
1     A    0.1
1     B    0.6
1     C    0.3
2     A    0.7
2     C    0.3
```

How can I rearrange the records to make the table looks like this and write to another txt file in Python:

```
GROUP TYPE_A TYPE_B TYPE_C
1     0.1    0.6    0.3
2     0.7    0.0    0.3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    next(f, None) # skip header

    for line in f:
        group, type_, fraction = line.split()
        d[group][type_] = fraction

types = sorted(set(k for g in d.values() for k in g))

print 'GROUP ' + ''.join('{:<7}'.format('TYPE_' + t) for t in types)
for i, g in sorted(d.items()):
    print '{0:<6}'.format(i) + ''.join('{:<7}'.format(g.get(k, 0.0)) 
                                       for k in types)
```

Output:

```
GROUP TYPE_A TYPE_B TYPE_C 
1     0.1    0.6    0.3    
2     0.7    0.0    0.3
```

Comment: @downvoter I request for you to take back the downvote unless you can explain to me why you think this was not a useful answer.